# How to identify (named) different visitor for create 1 visitor 1 folder in dir?

Tags: php, javascript, store

I try to make webpage flow like below, and have question:
Q1- in (2), need to named folder to identify different visitor, because not asking them login before, so should I make a function check visitor IP(bad Idea) or Mac address and use the value to named Or better idea?

Flow-
(1) visitor upload file(img)
(2) store img in server add new folder named ? (1 visitor 1 folder in dir)
(3) show the img on page
(4) visitor can edit (rotate, resize or delete) img on page

(5-1) visitor finish edit, confirm publish (asking login)
(6) move img folder in server, give new name by login username

(5-2) visitor leave website, (not continued login)
(6) remove img folder in server. folder name ?

**[UPDATE]

I use session still have same problem- how to named the different visitor?**

**Now I'm trying named by count how many folder in dir and `++`, but in this case if after (6), then once create new folder, name possible duplicate in dir..**
Example: there are 3 visitor online edit and 3 folder(named `v1`, `v2`, `v3`) in dir. then if `v2` remove or move. Now new visitor come how to avoid named v3?
Or better idea?

Comment: Why can't you ask them to login?

Comment: because I try to catch visitor use the flow

Comment: You can use [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Comment: ip is not person, one ip can be many people. or one person many ip

Comment: @hendry.fu should I do like this: add a new session[tmp_username] and named folder [tmp_username], in (5-2) just remove the [tmp_username]

Comment: @Dagon yep ip is the bad idea...

Comment: just a bad idea to do anything like this with out a proper login \visitor tracking system, what are you going to do when people find out how easy it is to edit others images?

Comment: @Dagon other images? you mean other visitor image? no, purpose the visitor upload and edit own images. save temporary before login, and after login or leave, to do move or remove.

Comment: well they eil be able to if you do something as silly as rely on ip.

Comment: @hendry.fu but the session name should I named by visit website 1st 2nd (will be duplicate) or ?

Comment: Yes, you can give a temporary username. I don't quite understand what you mean by *but the session name should I named by visit website 1st 2nd (will be duplicate) or ?*

Comment: @hendry.fu I mean I have to let one visitor upload files all in one folder (convenient move or remove). But I don't know how to named the different visitor folder? Now I'm coding named by count how many folder in dir and ++, but in this case if in (6), once create new folder, name possible duplicate in dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate and track a session cookie when someone visits the page. Using the IP or mac address (if you can get it) isn't ideal because many people can share one IP address with technology like NAT (network address translation).

Check out the PHP session documentation for more information:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: should I do like this: add a new session[tmp_username] and named folder [tmp_username], in (5-2) just remove the [tmp_username]

Comment: but I have to let one visitor upload files all in one folder (convenient move or remove). I don't know how to named the different visitor folder? Now I'm coding named by count how many folder in dir and ++, but in this case if in (6), once create new folder, name possible duplicate in dir